How can my Android activity ignore the onDestroy caused by the user bolds/unbolds the system font?
My NativeActivity ignores many config changes so it doesn't get unnecessarily destroyed, but I'm unable to ignore the onDestroy when a Samsung user bolds/unbolds the system font.
Steps that reproduce consistently:

Load my game
Go to Settings->Display->Font size and style
Toggle "Bold font"
Switch back to game
Game receives onDestroy

My manifest has multiple values for "android:configChanges" but none of them work for bolding and unbolding the font. Is there an undocumented value that would do this or a value that's specific to Samsung OneUI?
